# How to fetch an array object from json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

JSON: [https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py](https://www.cc.puv.fi/%7Easa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py)

Im trying to fetch objects and arrays within the object but im only fetching the objects.

How do i fetch also "products" arrays?

My javascript code:

```
fetch('https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(teksti => tulostus(teksti))

function tulostus(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
    let tilaukset = JSON.parse(txt);
     console.log(tilaukset);

    let a = "<table><tr><th>orderid</th><th>customerid</th><th>customer</th><th>invaddr</th><th>delivaddr</th><th>deliverydate</th><th>respsalesperson</th><th>comment</th><th>totalprice</th></tr>";
    for(let i = 0; i < tilaukset.length; i++) {
        let tilaus = tilaukset[i];
        console.log(tilaus)
        console.log(tilaus.orderid);
        a += '<tr><td>' + tilaus.orderid + '</td><td>' + tilaus.customerid + '</td><td>' + tilaus.customer + '</td><td>' + tilaus.invaddr + '</td><td>' + tilaus.delivaddr + '</td><td>' + tilaus.deliverydate + '</td><td>' + tilaus.respsalesperson + '</td><td>' + tilaus.comment + '</td><td>' + tilaus.totalprice + '</td></tr>'
    }   
    console.log(a);
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = a+'</table>';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question, and _not_ as images. It's very difficult to debug an image. You can add code using the snippet tool `[<>]` in the toolbar.

Comment: `.py` is a sketchy/confusing extension for JSON.  [Valid JSON is not necessarily valid Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977437/can-valid-json-be-invalid-python)  (If that's even what that extension means)

Comment: @Wyck that's a url, it's quite possibly responding with the header `Content-Type: "application/json"`

Comment: Why do you use `.text` instead of `.json` when parsing a json?

Comment: Ah I get it now.  It's a python "cgi" script that is serving up the JSON.  My bad.  Makes sense.  I think my eyes glossed over `cgi-bin` the first time I read it.

Answer (score 0):

You likely are fetching the products array but need to add some code to iterate over it.

```
    for(let i = 0; i < tilaukset.length; i++) {
        let tilaus = tilaukset[i];
        console.log(tilaus)
        console.log(tilaus.orderid);
        a += '...'

        for (let j=0; j < tilaus.products.length; j++) {
          console.log(tilaus.products[i].name);
        }
    }
```

Replace the console log in the loop with some code to write to the html as you were doing above. Depending on how you'd like it to look at might get tricky, so consider abstracting away HTML generation or using a library that helps you componentize the ui.

Answer (score 0):

```
    fetch("https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py").
        then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => display(result))

    let display = (result) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            let products = result[i].products 
            // here products is a Object array

            for(let i=0;i<products.length;i++){
                let product = products[i];
                console.log(product)
                // add your stuff here like product.orderid to get orderid
            }
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you're already looping over the array and getting the object from there, if you check there's product array there in every array value(tialus.products) just save that value in a variable